# Convert column with dates (as strings) into date type with only the year

Tags: r, date, dataframe, formatting

I have a dataset (call it `df`) that has several columns. One of those columns is the column `date`, which has strings of the form "d-MON-yy" or "dd-MON-yy" depending on if the day number is less than 10 (e.g. 9-Jan-04, 15-Oct-98) or `NA`.
I am trying to change this to date type values, but I only need the year. Specifically, all the dates whose yy digits are less than 20 are from this century, and all the dates whose yy digits are greater than or equal to 20are from the 1900s. I want to have the four numbers of the year in the end.

Since I am only interested in the year, I don't mind a solution that returns numeric values.

In the end, I'd like to also filter out the rows that have `NA` on *the `date` variable only.

I am pretty new to R, and I have tried to make it work with several answers I found here to no avail.

Thank you.

Comment: What you're asking for is to convert to `Date` and then convert to either `integer` or `character`, is that right? There's no data-type that is "just year".

Comment: So for that, you could use `as.Date` and then `format`. However, if you always have strings ending in `-yy`, you can short-cut it with `paste0("20", substr(x, nchar(x)-1, nchar(x)))`

Comment: In that case, I don't mind skipping the conversion to `Date`. I just want to obtain the year as an `integer`

Comment: But in this case, I will end up with years like 2085 instead of 1985

Comment: One way would be `library(lubridate); df$year = year(dmy(df$date))`

Comment: Since you only show `-98`, then whatever year it is is ambiguous, so you can handle that logic yourself. (It might be sufficient to say "less than current year, it must be 19", I have no idea what your context is.)

Comment: @r2evans I was very specific: "(...) all the dates whose yy digits are less than 20 are from this century, and all the dates whose yy digits are greater than or equal to 20 are from the 1900s."

Comment: Dates require year month and day of month but you can print them with only year using format.

Comment: TheBosco, my suggestion to use `paste0("20",...)` was purely demonstrative, I'd think you could set that to `"19"` or whatever is appropriate. If you want ints, then wrap that in `as.integer`.

Comment: If it is vectorized, how do I go about doing this with if statements? I have never programed in R before. Or how can I execute a conditional `paste0`?

Comment: TheBosco, forgive me for not latching on to that ... sure. But are you asking for logic on how to do `ifelse(yy < 20, "20" ,"19")`?

Comment: So I can just pass the whole `ifelse(yy < 20, "20", "19")` as an argument? That's pretty neat